# magento - theming buttons

Tags: css, magento, button, theming

I want to re-theme major buttons in Magento 1.7 with a CSS rounded button with background color.  I hacked-up the following code, which works in most places, except for some unwanted background on the search button and the "Proceed to Checkout" button.  Does anyone have a more complete and tested recipe to do this?

```
button.button span span
{
    background: blue !important;            
    color: black !important;
    background-color:none !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;  
} 

button.button span
{
    background: blue  !important;       
    padding:3px 8px 3px 8px !important; 
    border-radius:15px !important;  
    border:0px ;    
    margin:0px ;    
    font-weight:normal  !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;    
}
```

Comment: do you have the button code, or a link, or picture?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you have styled the `<span>` tags containing the text within the buttons, but you've not styled the buttons themselves.

You need to add CSS for button.button (and button.button:hover), or remove/change the existing CSS being applied to it in styles.css.